# Select rows where previous row under ordering on one column meets some condition

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I'm trying to figure how often it happens that a user opens our email, but hadn't opened any of our emails for one week. The query looks something like

```
select * from user_email_tracking uet1 where opened_timestamp is not null and
    select(max(opened_timestamp) from user_email_tracking where user_id = uet1.user_id
    and opened_timestamp < uet1.opened_timestamp
```

Even if I figure that nested select out, it's probably way too inefficient. This is a rather huge table. The logic I'm working on right now is probably not good enough, since I need to essentially work on an actual full cartesian join, below the diagonal created by the field I care about.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a correlated subquery, such as the following:

```
select *
from user_email_tracking uet
where opened_timestamp is not null and
      not exists (select 1
                  from user_email_tracking uet2
                  where uet2.user_id = uet.user_id and
                        uet2.opened_timestamp >= date_add(uet1.opened_timestamp, interval -7 day)
                 );
```

I assumed that `timestamp` is a `datetime` for convenience in doing the date arithmetic.

For best performance, you want an index on `user_email_tracking(user_id, user_email_tracking)`.

Comment: Well, "one solution is a correlated subquery"... such as the above

Comment: I blanked on the correlation step, but it's way not efficient enough.